# How to deal with this Python sundials library error?

Tags: python, sundials, assimulo

I'm trying to use the assimulo library in Python to solve differential-algebraic equations. I am programming this in Spyder using the anaconda environment. I have used mamba to install assimulo (since conda itself was incredibly slow and kept ending up in errors) and mamba installed assimulo, including sundials, successfully. However, trying to import the IDA solver, I get following error:

```
Could not find libsundials_sunlinsolsuperlumt.so.4.6.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~/anaconda3/envs/olderPythonVersion/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File ~/Desktop/testscript.py:11
    from solver import Solver

  File ~/Desktop/solver.py:10
    from assimulo.solvers import IDA
```

I am quite a novice to Python and have spent about 80% of my programming time to date trying to get packages to work (hence I am very frustrated at this point). Any help or advice with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.

Comment: `I am quite a novice to Python and have spent about 80% of my programming time to date trying to get packages to work (hence I am very frustrated at this point)` That's your problem right there. If you're a novice to Python, you shouldn't be installing twenty libraries to get your code to work. Start with if statements, and for loops, and functions, and classes. You need to properly *learn* Python before throwing a zillion third-party packages into the mix, or you'll have no ability to debug what goes wrong. Forget `sundials` for now. Just focus on actual Python. There's no skipping ahead.

Comment: Fair point and thank you for replying, but I'm actually quite familiar with those concepts. I've done quite a bit of programming in Matlab and learning the equivalent python syntax isn't too difficult. The problem is that in Matlab I never had to bother with packages and I have no idea how things like conda and mamba operate. Do you have suggestions as to how I can learn how to address such package issues?

Comment: A `.so` file is a shared library. It's some code not written in Python (it's probably C) that you usually have to install separately. I don't know `sundials` so I can't speak to its installation procedures, but I'd say double check their install instructions and see if you missed a step. It's entirely possible they tell you how to get that `.so` file.